# Add a new Node to an running Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a running Hadoop 2.6.0 Cluster with 2 Node and 1 Master.
And now I'm trying to and another Node to the running cluster.

I've added the new Node to the `slaves` file and made the node accessible via SSH from the master.
Then I executed:

```
hadoop-daemons.sh --script hdfs start datanode
yarn-daemons.sh start nodemanager
```

I saw the datanode and nodemanager running on the node, but when i run on Master

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

I see only 2 nodes.
Can someone help me with this Problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try running hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes on the Master nodes?

Comment: Yes, but it changed nothing. But 'yarn node -list' returns '3'

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?